# Redis cache docker container with spring boot not working on my local Machine

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, redis

I am using redis cache on my local Machine as a docker image. I have enabled the cache for one of my method using the cacheable anothion. Application is not able to cache the same when i am using on aws it is working instead of localhost

```
public class RedisConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate() {

        System.out.println("localhost")
        System.out.println("6379");
        jedisConnectionFactory.getHostName();
        jedisConnectionFactory.getPort();

        RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
        // Number of seconds before expiration. Defaults to unlimited (0)
        cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(60);
        cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
        return cacheManager;
    }

}
@Cacheable(value="sgcode" , cacheManager ="cacheManager")
    public String getSegmentCode(String aname ) {
        Logger.info("code ", "##### SEGMENT METHOD CALLED ##### {}", aname);
        return segmentCodeMap.get(aname);       
    }

Logger line will be printed only once after that it should fetch from cache.
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally after lot of struggle found the root cause. use the enablecaching anotation in application class